# Which Sci-Fi/Horror movie is referenced in The Iron Giant?

Tags: the-iron-giant

In the Iron Giant, Hogarth Hughes is a huge sci-fi lover. Left home alone, he stays up late watching a sci-fi movie that creeps him out a bit. It feels very familiar, but I can't place it.

- It's black and white
- It has a scientist experimenting on a brain
- The brain falls to the floor, "ruining" it
- The scientist decides to leave and ignore the brain
- The brain seems to grow into a monster and begin attacking people

I know that this is probably not a specific recreation of a movie, but that it's probably a reference to some other movie. Is there anything that this seems to match up best with?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the scifi movies of the period, but that scene feels more like a pastiche of the tropes prevalent at the time: macho men, dainty ladies, cavalier science, science gone horribly wrong, the *shock* music... etc.

Comment: It's entirely possible - and that would explain why it feels *so* familiar.

Comment: I know! When I first saw it, I could've sworn that I've seen that movie before.

Answer (score 5):

A classic scene that seems to capture pulp sci fi perfectly.

Its no specific movie but I would say it definitely is a homage to "Fiend without a Face" 1958 and "The Brain from Planet Arous" 1957.

Comment: Awesome! You could improve this answer by explaining the links/similarities.

Answer (score 1):

[*Donovan's Brain*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045699/) was a 1953 film about a scientist who manages to keep a human brain alive in a laboratory. The brain belonged to a ruthless businessman, and it learns to take over the bodies of nearby people and force them to do its bidding.

The main difference from *The Iron Giant* is that Donovan's brain couldn't physically move.